# OnLongClickListener not working in custom framelayout

Tags: android

I have a custom FrameLayout that has an imageview in it, the whole Essence of this was to create a draggable imageview which works fine using OnTouch, but since View.OnTouchListener is always listenning and updating views there came times when I did not want to drag but since I touched the view i found myself dragging the view so I thought of using View.OnLongClickListener to call the View.OnTouchListener and as soon as I let go it would stop the View.OnTouchListener from listening for screen touches, but to my surprise View.OnLongClickListener is not working below is my View.OnLongClickListener object and listener:

```
 framelayout.setOnLongClickListener(onLongClickListener);
 .
 .
 .

private View.OnLongClickListener onLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener()
{

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

    framelayout.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchToDrag);

    Toast.makeText(thisContext, "Am here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return false;
}
 };
```

Comment: Is the "Am here" toast running?

Comment: Maybe it would help to add setLongClickable(false) to your onLongClick() code, so that you're not calling it over and over again unnecessarily?

Comment: am here is not running

Comment: i tried that too nothing worked

Comment: am from implementing View.OnLongClickListener and still nothing, but onTouch works perfectly

Comment: And is it throwing any exceptions?

Comment: here is my full code, u could comment from this post, I couldnt get enough traffic from here so i thought of making another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305360/onlongclicklistener-not-working-in-custom-framelayout-android