# OnLongClickListener not working in custom framelayout Android

Tags: android

I have an ImageView in a FrameLayout, I want to setup LongClickListener but its failing to work, I tried setting up OnTouchListener and its working flawless, I do not have the slightest idea as to why its not working but below is my code code:

```
public class DragImageView extends FrameLayout implements View.OnLongClickListener {
ImageView ivDrag;

public DragImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);


}



public DragImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}



public DragImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void AddImageView(View draggableObject, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    LayoutParams lpDraggableView = new LayoutParams(width, height);
    lpDraggableView.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    lpDraggableView.leftMargin = x;
    lpDraggableView.topMargin = y;
    if(draggableObject instanceof ImageView) {
        this.ivDrag = (ImageView) draggableObject;
        ivDrag.setLayoutParams(lpDraggableView);
        ivDrag.setClickable(true);
        ivDrag.setLongClickable(true);
        ivDrag.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        this.addView(ivDrag);

    }

}

/**
 * Draggable object ontouch listener
 * Handle the movement of the object when dragged and dropped
 */
private View.OnTouchListener OnTouchToDrag =new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams dragParam = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {

                dragParam.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                dragParam.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                v.setLayoutParams(dragParam);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                dragParam.height = v.getHeight();
                dragParam.width = v.getWidth();
                dragParam.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                dragParam.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                v.setLayoutParams(dragParam);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                dragParam.height = v.getHeight();//fixed on drag and drop
                dragParam.width = v.getWidth();
                v.setLayoutParams(dragParam);
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

};




@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
  ivDrag.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchToDrag);
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "OnLongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
 }
```

Comment: Why is one of your constructors called DragDropView? Also, generally speaking, it is suggested not to use instanceof.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo error when pasting the code from my editor, its actually DragImageView, what do you think could be the problem, i was trying out something and it worked, except its not the imageview thats getting the LongClickListener, its the Windows containing the imageview

Comment: I'm not sure. Just for testing, have you tried changing it to an OnClick listener and see if that works?

Comment: I havent, let me try that

Comment: Hmm, I'm really not sure. What I would do is make your question much clearer and more concise, and be sure to specify that it works with onClickListener. Then more people will read your question and answer.

Comment: Please do that I will appreciate

Comment: I mean you should do that. Just put the basic details.

Comment: thank you and I have done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to setup LongClickListener but its failing to work

You are not receiving the callbacks from `OnLongClickListener` because it has no set listener. Since your class implements `View.OnLongClickListener` and you want to receive the callback in your overridden `onLongClick()` method, add this class itself as the listener and it will work. I've done so in the constructor (choose the appropriate constructor out of the three as per your initialization of the view):

```
public DragImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnLongClickListener(this); // <-- set this class instance as the listener
}
```

Although I'm surprised how you got it working with `OnTouchListener`. You probably explicitly added the listener, right?

Comment: Look at his AddImageView method.

Comment: @geokavel that method is never called as far as I can see. The listener needs to be added, either in (1) the constructor, or (2) using `setOnLongClickListener()` on an instance of `DragImageView` obtained by `findViewById()` in some other class. Or, just call the `AddImageView` method from the constructor.

Comment: Some other class is definitely calling it, because he is dragging the imageView in the FrameLayout, not the FrameLayout itself. He's said it works fine when he changed everything to OnClickListener, it just doesn't work with OnLongClickListener.

Comment: @geokavel yes i see it now. I thought this was a simple matter of not setting the listener and didn't look deep enough. I'll look for a proper solution.

Comment: This is interesting. I tried the same code and it works. I declared a DragImageView in xml, made a tiny .png for the imageview and used this in a corresponding activity. 
`ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

        iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.small);
        DragImageView div = (DragImageView)findViewById(R.id.drag_image_view);
        div.AddImageView(iv, 40, 40, 80, 80);` 
The imageview can be dragged around as it is supposed to, although a bit far off from the finger touch point. Let us know if something works out.